# Simple Thread started as Daemon thread

Tags: java, spring

I have created a simple thread when server starts up using Spring InitializingBean but started as Daemon thread,why it's started as daemon thread and is there any issue arise for long run in application. Or else i can start the thread by `setDaemon(false)`, please suggest.

```
public class Update implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    Service service
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        String hostname = Util.getServerName();
        service.updateStatus(hostName);
        Thread t1=new Thread(new UpdateService(service));
        t1.start();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that your service just terminates? A new thread is by default never a daemon

Comment: No, the thread started and running as a Daemon thread. When i am setting **t1.setDaemon(false);**  it started as a normal thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a main Thread (non daemon Thread), the JVM will not exit until that Thread is finished executing. So if you use `Thread.setDaemon(false);` then you must make sure that you dispose the Thread properly when the `ApplicationContext` is being disposed. You can use `DisposableBean` interface `destroy()` method to achieve this.

Or you can simply use a Daemon Thread.

Answer (score 0):

A daemon thread is a thread that does not prevent the JVM from exiting when the program finishes but the thread is still running. An example for a daemon thread is the garbage collection.

You can use the setDaemon(boolean) method to change the Thread daemon properties before the thread starts.
Example:

```
DaemonThread t = new DaemonThread();
        t.setDaemon(false);
```